# Large polygon with null geometry

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, watershed, null-geometry

I have a flood hazard area polygon that I'm creating based on a depth raster for a HUC 8 watershed. The script tool I use is as follows:

```
import arcpy, os


arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = False


matrix = """AREA <= 10890 Or 
(AREA > 10890 And AREA <= 21780 And MEAN < 0.5) Or 
(AREA > 21780 And AREA <= 43560 And MEAN < 0.25) Or 
(AREA > 43560 And AREA <= 87120 And MEAN < 0.1)"""

def applyMatrix(in_raster):
            
    in_raster = arcpy.Raster(in_raster)
    base_name = in_raster.name.split(".")[0]
    out_raster = arcpy.sa.Int(in_raster)
    out_raster = arcpy.sa.RegionGroup(out_raster, "FOUR", "CROSS", "NO_LINK", None)
    #Update for 2.7 to only have 6 arguments, not 7
    zsTable = arcpy.sa.ZonalStatisticsAsTable(out_raster, "Value", in_raster, r"memory\\zsTable", 
                                              "DATA", "MEAN")
    arcpy.management.JoinField(out_raster, "OBJECTID", zsTable, "OBJECTID", ["AREA","MEAN"])
    out_raster.save(os.path.join(out_path, "TEST_" + base_name))
    out_raster = arcpy.sa.SetNull(out_raster, out_raster, matrix)
    with arcpy.EnvManager(outputZFlag="Disabled", outputMFlag="Disabled"):
        polygon = arcpy.conversion.RasterToPolygon(out_raster, r"memory\\polygon", "NO_SIMPLIFY", "OBJECTID", "SINGLE_OUTER_PART", None)
    #Name error: Occurs when file starting with a number is saved to a geodatabase
    polygon = arcpy.management.EliminatePolygonPart(polygon, os.path.join(out_path, "Polygon_" + base_name), 
                                          "AREA", "13068 SquareFeet", 0, "CONTAINED_ONLY")
    out_raster = arcpy.sa.ExtractByMask(in_raster, out_raster) 
    out_raster = (arcpy.sa.Int(out_raster*10 + 0.5))/10
    out_raster.save(os.path.join(out_path, "Cleaned_" + base_name))
    del polygon, out_raster

if __name__ == '__main__':


    in_raster = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
    out_path = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

    applyMatrix(in_raster)
```

After I get the polygon from this, I run several processes to create a polygon of patches to fill in holes that are created from the raster

**Polygon to Line**: Converts the polygon to lines which will let me make features out of the holes

**Feature to Poly**: Creates polygons out of every space, including those that were empty in the original polygon. This gives me a polygon you can merge back into the original to fill holes.

**Feature Class to Feature Class**: Selects polygons that are less than or equal to 2 acres in area. I use these to go back and fill in the empty spaces in the polygon outputted by the script tool.

**Dissolve**: Dissolves touching features together so there are fewer total features (this completes the patch polygons, they’re now ready to be used to patch holes)

**Merge**: Fills the holes in the polygon outputted by the script tool with the polygon of patches

**Dissolve 2**: Dissolves merged polygons together so there aren’t polygons within polygons

Once the holes have been filled I smooth by 25 ft and check geometry. This usually throws a 9999 Error, so to remedy this I've been creating Cartographic Partitions then running Intersect on the polygon and check geometry then. The only warnings I get is self intersections (there are many after smoothing) so I run repair geometry to fix this. Then I dissolve the repaired polygon without creating multipart features to reverse the intersection I ran.

I believe this should have fixed any geometry issues with my polygon, however when I run Check Geometry one last time and it gives the warning 000442 "One or more of the parts of the geometry is null" and this is always the large main stream polygon. I have recreated this whole process multiple times and still get null geometry.

What is causing this and how can I fix this without having to remove the main stream?

Comment: Each of those processes can produce errors if the input has errors. They can even produce errors if the input *doesn't* have errors. Therefore you need to increase the frequency of Repair Geometry use.